# How to get the numero of each wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-hook

I'm searching a way to know for each post, its numero - eg: published post numero 23 on 100

Is it possible to do this WITHOUT using `get_posts`, counting and set the numero, one by one?

My goal: customize the callback of the WP REST API `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=`, to have the numero for each post in the response.

Any idea?

Comment: So you want the API to only return the post ID?

Comment: No because the post ID doesn't match with its numero. The post with the ID 15 can be in reality the 10th published post.

Comment: Ok. I don't think this is possible with the vanilla API. However if you check the response headers there is a header called 'X-WP-Total'. This will contain the total number of posts. Assuming you have ordered the API call by date you could calculate it using the array index?

Comment: In fact, I already do this, client side, using the array index.